# Autofac aop wildcard: is it possible?

Tags: autofac

The canonical way of using AOP in Autofac is to declare interceptor on each component:

```
builder.RegisterType<Filter1>().As<IFilter>()
  .EnableInterfaceInterceptors();
```

In my project I have a lot (tens of) IFilter implementations, so adding and maintaining them is inconvenient. I would prefer an ability to intercept all instances of service. Something like:

```
builder.EnableInterfaceInterceptors<IFilter>();
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if `EnableInterfaceInterceptors` can handle multiple registrations, but if it can this should work:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies).Where(t => t.IsAssignableTo<IFilter>())
    .EnableInterfaceInterceptors();
```

If you need, this can be wrapped into an extension method (like almost all the ContainerBuilder registration methods) to give you the exact syntax you requested above.